# Windows Phone: Different Icon per Language

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

is it possible to have a different appIcon in the app itself and in the Store, based on the current language of the phone/store page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It's not possible to have language specific `Icons` neither in Store nor in Application.

If you want to detect current language of device you can use `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` or `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`. But it's inside the application. So if you want to change any icon or image from inside Application in any of it's page, you can, but you can't change App Icon in the `All Apps` section of phone.

Hope that helps..

Comment: Okay thanks, I know how it works inside the Application. It seems possible in the new WP8 Store but still not in the App.